# Lists are currently not supported in HTML Input

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having this problem with my browsable API: "Lists are not currently supported in HTML input."

Here are my models:

```
class Breed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class BreedImage(models.Model):
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, related_name='BreedImages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breedImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True, blank=True)
```

My Serializers:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BreedImage
        fields = ['id', 'breedImage']   

class BreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    BreedImages = ImageSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = ['name', 'BreedImages']
```

My view:

```
class BreedList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer
    pagination_class = None
```

Answer (score 0):

"Lists are not currently supported in HTML input." is a default message of Django Rest Framework. This doesn't work in DRF and is not per se a bug/mistake.