# "This Field is Required" even though I am uploading my file

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload, django-rest-framework

This is a follow up question to my last question: [Lists are currently not supported in HTML Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455702/lists-are-currently-not-supported-in-html-input) . I have learned that Lists are simply not supported in Django-Rest-Framework browsable API, and I am trying to test my ability to POST data using Postman.

The error I am getting is: "This Field is Required" for my BreedImages field even though I am posting it.

Here are some pictures:

[image]

[image]

Here are my models:

```
class Breed(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.name

class BreedImage(models.Model):
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed, related_name='BreedImages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breedImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True, blank=True)
```

My Serializers:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BreedImage
        fields = ['id', 'breedImage']   

class BreedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    BreedImages = ImageSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Breed
        fields = ['name', 'BreedImages']
```

My view:

```
class BreedList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
    queryset = Breed.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BreedSerializer
    pagination_class = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to send data like `{"name": "Hello", "BreedImages": [img.png, img2.png]}` and save in Model in one request?

Comment: I am ok with just sending pictures one by one as well. This error happened to me in that situation.

Comment: because BreadImages field is waiting list dict with "id" and "breedImage" keys, not a list images. If you want give list files with POST, you need replace row from 
`BreedImages = ImageSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=True)` to
 
`BreedImages = serializers.ListField(source="BreedImages.breed", allow_null=True, required=True)`

and rewrite `def create(self, validated_data):` method with custom logics